# So, I just learned about the "ambiguous" case of the law of sines.

Tags: geometry

Explained above, there is this one condition with acute angles (saying that the triangle is A-a opposite, B-b opposite, and C-c opposite.)

Given angle(A), side a, and side b, if h < a < b (where h is the height of the incomplete triangle), Why does this give 2 triangles?

An example: a = 8, b = 9, $m\angle{A}$ = 35 degrees.

So, I found out that finding the height is $\sin(A) = \frac{h}{b}$

Substituting A and b, I get $\sin(35) = \frac{h}{9}$

This will equal to $9\sin(35) = h$

So, $h = 5.16$ (rounded to the hundredths)

So, $5.16 < 8 < 9$

Comment: See [The Ambiguous Case of the Law of Sines](http://www.softschools.com/math/calculus/the_ambiguous_case_of_the_law_of_sines/).

Comment: This only helps to solve 1 or both triangles, but it doesn't show the conditions to show if there are 1, 2, or no triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Construct angle $A$ first. Then draw a circle of radius $b$ with $A$ as a center. What do we see? The circle will intersect sides of the angle at two points so we have two possible locations for point $C$. Choose either one and draw a circle of radius $a$. That circle may intersect side $AB$ at one, two or no points depending on $a$. That's where the ambiguity comes from. There is no ambiguity if we are given two sides and an angle between them as this condition defines one and only one triangle (even though we still have two possible locations for $C$, picking either point will result in a triangle with the same sides).

Comment: Though it explains something of the meaning of "ambiguous", this still doesn't show that $h<a<b$ iff in ambiguous (two solutions) case.